# Paypal Vault and IOS mobile SDK

Tags: paypal

Can we store or use the vault feature of paypal via the IOS Mobile SDK?

I know we have to use the REST API to verify the payment after it has been made - Can we also call the vault API to store the customers credit card so that the customer doesn't have to renter their credit card details again when using our app?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify - We the user of our app to essentially use their CC to process a payment. Once processed we want to verify they payment and store the funding source with a payerID (UDID within our server side system). When that user returns we wish to use their 'stored' details as opposed to them entering their CC details agian.

Answer (score 3):

Dave from PayPal here.

Within the PayPal iOS SDK we do store the customer's credit card information (using the PayPal vault), so that your customer can in the future make another payment using your app without needing to re-enter that information.

For this storage to occur, when you create the `PayPalPaymentViewController` you must pass in a non-nil `payerId` string. If for a subsequent payment you provide the same `payerId`, then the previously stored credit card information will be retrieved.

Comment: Is there any way to make transactions with different merchants as Adaptive API do not support with new SDK?

Comment: @Arvind at this time, the PayPal iOS SDK is designed to be used with only a single merchant (client id) per app. That will probably change at some point during 2015, when the REST APIs on which the SDK depends provide such functionality.

Comment: @Dave, I am using Web Service Call for Mobile PayPal (Card) purchase. How can I avail Vault feature for Native IOS App like mine?

Comment: @Meenu the PayPal iOS SDK (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) is a native library that you can incorporate into your app, which allows credit card purchase. If you are instead making your own server calls, then see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#vault